# Post form from html, get server response into jquery modal lightbox

Tags: jquery, post, lightbox

I have a straightforward html form on a page.

I am using colorbox although I would imagine any jquery lightbox would do - the issue here is trying to get the form response from the server into the jquery lightbox. Back in the day you could set form "target" and point it at an IFRAME. Obviously we don't do that now because of XSS vulnerabilities BUT...

How are we supposed to do this?

Does anyone have a working example, with code, that they can share? I am not looking for "use xxxxx lightbox" - or "use the $.post - I have tried. Either the lightbox doesn't open because it hasn't been instantiated in the correct way or it opens but it's empty and can't access either the date in parent.document (fair enough) or data from the server. I try instantiating inside document.ready - but I need it triggering onsubmit and if I trigger it on document.ready the values are incorrect - even though events aren't supposed to work like that, are they?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.post( url,
      function( data ) {

          // you have to open lightbox here.
          // and then you can fill it with result.

          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
```

you have to open lightbox when ajax request has been completed. I think you opened lightbox first and then you can't fill it up gently with post response since lightbox had width and height already. 
This is what I understand from  your post.

Comment: Hi @littlealien,

Thanks for your response.

All the lightboxes I have seen are set up when the page has loaded. They have: